# How to stop (or pause) the device's audio in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiosession, audiosession

I am making a music timer which will stop music (playing from Spotify, Apple Music, etc.) after an entered time. Is there a way to stop that audio session or pause the audio which is being played from another app from my app?

Since I don't have a local audio player in my app, I cannot just simply stop the player (as you usually would when playing audio from your app).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` stop anything another app is playing if you use the `.playback` category? If that doesn't work, you could always play a silent audio file...

Comment: Thank you! This code: try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) within a do catch statement worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import AVFoundation in the file which will stop the audio.
2. Add this code once the timer is done:

   ```
   do {
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
   } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
   ```